# Retrieve JSON from a website (Windows phone 7)

Tags: c#, json, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing an app that has foursquare in it. I am having problem in retrieving JSON from the website. How to do that in windows phone 7 ? The format of JSON is below:

> {"access_token":"j2hkjb4fgwt54gfdsfs"}

How to retrieve the JSON and store "j2hkjb4fgwt54gfdsfs" to a string variable ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

How about using [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/)? Then you'd do something like

```
JObject.Parse(jsonString)["access_token"].Value<string>()
```

Comment: sorry, can you explain more ?

Answer (score 1):

You really have two questions here:

1. How do you get the data from Foursquare?
2. How do you parse the data once you have it?

There are many different ways to accomplish each of those.

Retrieving data could be done with [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx), or any number of 3rd party libraries such as [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).

Parsing the data could be done with JSON.Net (as spender mentioned), [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx), or probably any number of other libraries.

Comment: how to perform that if i'm using a WebClient ?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? The MSDN page I linked to has an example for doing exactly that.

Comment: I saw the documentation. But I don't know how what works since i'm a newbie. Can you help me ?

Comment: I would suggest that you copy the example code and get it running. Read the documentation for whatever you don't understand. Then start making the changes that might be needed for Foursquare's particular APIs.